# Angular 1 export html to pdf with css?

Tags: angularjs

I have a task where I need to export the html to pdf.Where the pdf should have same design as it has in browser.Basically I need the css should also work in pdf file. Am using angularjs for front end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2bEEMBc8EepKPQhZxH18?p=preview) First run pdfSample.js on cmd as -- node pdfsample.js 
 Then include html and js file in your workspace where you want to get pdf . Then try running as you do .It will work.

```
   pdf.create(renderedHtml, options).toStream(function (err, stream) {

    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    console.log("*****inside pdf create ******");

    stream.pipe(res);
   stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('invoice.pdf'));
});
```